# Close then Open Workbook

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have a need to close the workbook i have a macro in and then reopen it after closing.

It is at the end of a process that makes various changes in some setting values and then saves a copy of the changed file.  after saving the changed file, i then want to Close the current workbook (no save changes) and then open it so that way i can open it as it was before the changes occurred.

If there is a better way than Close then Open, by all means ill take advise.

This logic needs to happen in the Workbook and not anywhere outside of the Working Workbook, IE no Personal.xlsm or other personal method locations that will not travel with the workbook.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
dim currentworkbookPath as string
'Store current workbook path to a string
currentworkbookPath = workbook.FullName
'Save the workbook somewhere else
Workbook.SaveAs 'I'll let you figure out the save as details yourself :P 
'Open the old workbook.
Workbooks.Open currentworkbookPath
'Close the saved workbook.
Workbook.Close
```

Where Workbook is the actual workbook you're working with, you'll probably want to use `ThisWorkbook`, but I didn't feel like assuming.

Incase you're not familiar here is the reference for [Workbook.FullName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834975.aspx)

Comment: wasnt sure if i could open the same file before closing it....ill try it and see what happens.  Not doubting it but seeing is believing.

Comment: You can re-open it because you've already renamed the current file by saving it as something else. If you really wanted to open the same file twice, you could create a new instance of Excel and open it in that... though it'd have to be read-only.

Comment: having issues with some `Volatile` cells not updating on the Workbook_Open, ultimately after i get the alert that i am opening a file that is already open.  Any way to delay the opening of the file until after it has been closed?

Comment: Actually i am using `wb.SaveCopyAs Newfilename` instead of changing the current filename.

Comment: Oh... use SaveAs instead. When you save using SaveAs, the file that you want to re-open is no longer open because the open version gets renamed. We could work around it and use SaveCopyAs, that would require the workbook to be closed before opening the unedited version, which would stop the code and result in the workbook not opening.

Comment: yeah was doing that at one point but needed to retain the current instance of the Workbook open, but the logic has since changed to where i need to close the current Workbook and then Open it back up without saving any Changes made.  Any situation that would cause `Workbook_Open` not to trigger?  GOing to implement the `SaveAs` and see if any other problem incurred.

Comment: Workbook_open should always trigger when a workbook is opened, unless VBA is disabled due to Trust level or being in break mode within the application. Workbook will run after the open line in the code I provided.

Comment: When i work in the `First` Workbook, then rename it, and then reopen the `First` workbook.  Getting a `Application-defined or object-defined` error...thinking it might be due to some Workbook-defined variable/objects i utilize.  How do i resolve this?

Comment: Since i am opening the file and loading some settings from a Worksheet, and then, during this process, save the file to a different name.  How do i make it so that the objects declared on initial load do not conflict when i reopen the file?

Comment: You're resaving the workbook during the Workbook_Open procedure? Could you post this as a different question so you can flesh out the details and get other users interested again?

Comment: ok posted Further error question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13123980/reopen-workbook-results-in-application-defined-or-object-defined